# Zyxel C3000Z VDSL modem: extra shell password?

Tags: home-networking, telnet, password-recovery, adsl-router, vdsl

I have a Zyxel C3000A ADSL/VDSL modem (CenturyLink branding). I have searched, and it seems it is not possible to purchase this device *without* CenturyLink branding and firmware.

The device has the most recent firmware installed as I write this (**CZD005-4.16.011.0**).

I can ssh to the device without issues:

```
login as: admin
admin@192.168.0.1's password: <entered my password>
>
```

However, when I try to run the **sh** command to access the shell, I get prompted for a password again. I tried a username of **admin** and my ssh password, but all I get is:

```
> sh
Please input shell credential to login
Login:admin
Password: <entered my password again>
Password Incorrect! Try again.
```

I also tried a username of **admin** and the default password of the device (on the device's sticker), but that password doesn't work either.

In other words: There is an **ADDITIONAL** password to access the **sh** prompt on the C3000Z. I don't see this additional password anywhere on the device or in the configuration GUI.

I have performed a reset of the device but the additional **sh** password is still there.

Does anyone know what credentials to use for **sh** console access on the CenturyLink C3000Z device?

Comment: "latest firmware provided by CenturyLink" Clearly you should ask CenturtyLink support about this issue.

Comment: First problem, you purchased a CenturyLink branded modem, with CenturyLink specific firmware, instead of a retail "unlocked" or unbranded version and expect full control over the product. Honestly, they may not give you that access or password, whether you own the modem or not. The only way may be to get get the firmware image and reverse engineer it, which may or may not be possible.

Comment: I would say that it is questionable whether they can legally prevent a device owner from gaining full access to said device.

Answer (score 0):

At least on the C1000A, this didn't use to be the case.  [It used to give shell access after `sh`](https://github.com/benjaminoakes/tiny-tiny-nas).  A firmware update sometime in the last few years might be why.

In other words, this appears to have been disabled and probably isn't accessible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've been in contact with someone who has a C1000A with firmware version CA004-31.30L.95 and has the same problem. We don't know what user/password it wants, but the extra lock can be bypassed using shell injection at the `>` prompt. Try typing `echo ;sh` or similar instead of `sh` after logging in:

```
$ telnet 192.168.0.1
Trying 192.168.0.1...
Connected to 192.168.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
===Actiontec xDSL Router===
Login: admin
Password: <password set in "Remote Console" GUI page>
 > echo ;sh



BusyBox v1.17.2 (2018-03-02 10:34:35 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

#
```

Comment: This does not work on the C3000Z.